# Можно ли использовать 2 разных концепта, на разных страницах?

Tags: веб-дизайн, ux

Есть два концепта для страницы сайта первый я хотел использовать для новостей, а второй для полезных сервисов но они разные в стилистики, можно ли их использовать на одном сайте, но на разных страницах(просто полезные сервисы могут быть как с картинкой так и без, могут состоять из одной строки а могут из нескольких предложений)?[image: для новостей]
[image: для полезных сервисов]

Comment: Это ваш продукт. Можно всё)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, только будет выглядеть как магазин на диване с рекламными роликами между блоками. Хорошо это или плохо на сегодняшний день отвечает рынок. Приносит прибыль есть спрос хорошо, нет ну и ...

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять условный юнит (например 16px/pt/em) и танцевать всю сетку от размеров этого юнита.

Например: https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html

Comment: не сетка готова просто вопрос можно ли использовать два концепта